# How call Bus::assertDispatched() in Laravel multiple times with specific order

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm trying to follow [this example from the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mocking#bus-fake):

```
Bus::fake();

// Perform order shipping...

Bus::assertDispatched(ShipOrder::class, function ($job) use ($order) {
    return $job->order->id === $order->id;
});
```

But in my case, I want to call `Bus::assertDispatched()` 4 times because my function dispatches a job 4 times with different constructor arguments.

When I run my test function with the 4 assertions in the order that they happen in the code, it often fails, and it seems that the *sort order* of the dispatching is random.

How can I fix this so that my test can expect the exact order of dispatched jobs?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it doesn't work to call multiple times, but instead I figured out that I could call it this way, passing `$counter` as a reference variable:

```
$counter = 1;
Bus::assertDispatched(\App\Jobs\EmailEncouragingEnrollmentJob::class, function ($job) use (&$counter) {
    $customMailable = $job->getCustomMailable();
    $this->assertEquals('emails.webcast.enrollmentReminder' . $counter, $customMailable->view);
    $counter++;
    return true;
});
```